# How to check if no new data entered, the App scripts will do nothing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets which have protected data range for example A2:F99, A100:F199 and so on. Now if new rows of data entered to A200 and onward, it is working fine. But if No new data is entered to A200 and onward for example, the highlighted block (**  **) of codes should not be executed. And when there is no new rows of data, that code block of codes between (**  **) works surprisingly on A1:F2. Please note that A1:F1 is not protected.

So how to code it when there will be no new data, the highlighted block of codes MUST not be executed.

```
  function onePeriod(){
  // For a single Period Class
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue();
  //retrieve the start date to use as desired
  var startDate = dashboard.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue();
  var endDate = dashboard.getRange("D4").getDisplayValue();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  //chose the range within the specified dates, for this first locate the date column
  var startRow = 2;
  var dateColumn = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var dates = dateColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var firstRow = dates.indexOf(startDate)+startRow;
  var lastRow = dates.lastIndexOf(endDate)+startRow;
  //now get the range between (and including) those rows
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow-firstRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var newRows = lastRow-firstRow;
  
  **if(newRows > 0){  
    //Sorting and removing duplicates
    // You need to specify by which column you want to sort your data, in this sample it it column 3 - that it column C  
    var column = 3;
    range.sort({column: column, ascending:true});
    range.removeDuplicates([column]);
  
    //now delete empty rows if any
    var deleteRows = 0;  // <--- Added
    for (var i = range.getHeight(); i >= 1; i--){
        if(range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()){
           sheet.deleteRow(range.getCell(i, 1).getRow());
           deleteRows++;
        }
    }
    
    //Protecting data 
    var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
    var height = range.getHeight();
    var newHeight = height+1;
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, newHeight-deleteRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  
    var protection = newRange.protect().setDescription(description);
    newRange.getCell(newHeight-deleteRows, 2).setValue(height-deleteRows + ' Students, Signed by ' + me).offset(0, -1, 1, 6).setBackground('#e6b8af');
    //protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }  
  }**
```

}

Comment: How are the new rows being inserted? By a human , formula or script? Also, by insert row, do you mean inserting additoinal rows with data or pasting data into existing empty rows?

Comment: By Human. Now I am testing it with manual insertion of rows of data (copy & paste of 3-4 rows and, then change Dates). But usually it comes from user through a mobile app in this format: Date Student ID-Name Umail Geoloc-Latitude Geoloc-Longitude Subject-code
2020-07-08 1802006 1802006@icte.bdu.ac.bd 25.755808 89.2412643 ICTE4215

Comment: Pasting data into existing empty rows. If (newRows > 0) ---this condition is not correct I think. It needs to be fixed.

Comment: `onePeriod();` is currently running only if `e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B4'`. This means that if you add a new row (and thus the added range will not be row 4) `onePeriod()` will never be called.

Comment: Please note that onEdit () is for a page name Dashboard and onePeriod is for the data entry page. I just want to check that after the last protected data range if there is any new data added or not. If not, then do not execute the highlighted code block.

Comment: I just wanted to show you the flow of codes execution. Please just leave the onEdit().

Comment: Please check the image of the Google Sheets. Upto A2:F186 data range is protected. What I want is just to check whether if there is NO rows of data inserted on A187 and onwards, then the highlighted code blocks won't be executed. If one or more rows of data are inserted, then that code blocks should be executed. That's All.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet copy with relevant data for testing?

Comment: Please check the link below the post. Also please test by inserting No rows of data, one rows of data, multiple rows.

Comment: This is the same spreadsheet with data I am testing now. You can check the scripts as well.

Comment: I see that you base the judgement of "new" depending on the dates. So what do you put in as start date and end date in Dashboard to recognize that the data from `2020-07-30` is new?

Comment: The start date and end date is the same date for example, 2020-07-30. So we need to check if there is no rows of data inserted on this particular date, that highlighted block of codes will NOT be executed otherwise it will be executed. That's all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218916/discussion-between-aktaruzzaman-liton-and-ziganotschka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are retrieving the first and the last index of the occurence of a date in the sheet
- If there is only one occurence - the first and the last index will be the same and thus `lastRow = firstRow` and `newRows = 0`
- This is why `newRows > 0` is not a good criterion
- If you want to query either a date does not occur at all - check either `dates.indexOf(startDate) == -1`
- As mentioned in the documentation for [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
> can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Adapting it to your case:

```js
//if startdate is present in column A
if(dates.indexOf(startDate) != -1){  
  //Sorting and removing duplicates
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's worked fine. Could you please check my another post where I have to add another clause with this conditions, that is, if the input start date is already there in a protected range of data, then it will also not execute that block of codes like this one.

Comment: Please find my another post with similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186913/how-to-avoid-a-block-of-apps-script-codes-execution-if-an-input-date-is-already