# How to avoid a block of Apps Script codes execution if an input date is already there in a protected range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to satisfy two conditions to execute a block of codes:

1. If there is no data of that particular date, it won't execute the highlighted block of codes [approx. last 30 lines of codes in the post]; The condition is if(dates.indexOf(startDate) != -1){  and it is working fine.
2. If there is an input date already exist in a protected range of data in Google Sheets, it also won't execute the same highlighted block of codes.

The input dates are always the current date and therefore, I think it should be searched only in the last protected range of data.

How to build the second condition and add it to the first condition provided that refreshSheet() and onePeriod() will execute one after another? Check the attached image also to know the issue better.

```
    function onePeriod(){
      // For a single Period Class
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
      var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue();
      //retrieve the start date to use as desired
      var startDate = dashboard.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue();
      var endDate = dashboard.getRange("D4").getDisplayValue();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      //chose the range within the specified dates, for this first locate the date column
      var startRow = 2;
      var dateColumn = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
      var dates = dateColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
      var firstRow = dates.indexOf(startDate)+startRow;
      var lastRow = dates.lastIndexOf(endDate)+startRow;
      //now get the range between (and including) those rows
      var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow-firstRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());
      
      //Sorting and removing duplicates
      // You need to specify by which column you want to sort your data, in this sample it it column 3 - that it column C  
      

**if(dates.indexOf(startDate) != -1){  
        var column = 3;
        range.sort({column: column, ascending:true});
        range.removeDuplicates([column]);
      
        //now delete empty rows if any
        var deleteRows = 0;  // <--- Added
        for (var i = range.getHeight(); i >= 1; i--){
            if(range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()){
               sheet.deleteRow(range.getCell(i, 1).getRow());
               deleteRows++;
            }
        }
        
        //Protecting data 
        var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
        var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
        var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
        var height = range.getHeight();
        var newHeight = height+1;
        var newRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, newHeight-deleteRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
      
        var protection = newRange.protect().setDescription(description);
        newRange.getCell(newHeight-deleteRows, 2).setValue(height-deleteRows + ' Students, Signed by ' + me).offset(0, -1, 1, 6).setBackground('#e6b8af');
        //protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        protection.addEditor(me);
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }  
      }**
}
```

Comment: If I understood it right - you want to verify either `range` is already protected or not before running the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes, protected range of a particular date, in the image it is 2020-07-31. As here in image there is a protected range of date 2020-07-31, the highlighted block of codes won't be executed for rows of data 192 and onwards for example.

Comment: So condition 1 [if(dates.indexOf(startDate) != -1)] OR condition 2 (this one) { the highlighted block of codes will be here }

Comment: Please note that the input dates are always the current date and therefore, I think it should be searched only in the last protected range of data or other ways you prefer to verify...

Comment: My condition is bit different than you thought. Two rows of data are just inserted in row 192 and 193 which are unprotected and on date 2020-07-31. Before doing anything on this two data, we need to check, is there any protected range of data with date 2020-07-31. In this case of the image, it is already there (A186:F191). So the highlighted block of codes won't be executed. Thus, highlighted code blocks won't do anything for row 192 and onward. So no need to check for unprotected data but rather you have to check for any protected range of date 2020-07-31. Hope that you got my point.

Comment: Could you please check my another post at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251082/facing-issues-while-executing-the-app-scripts-code-for-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to create an additonal condition for running a code block
- The condition is that `range` is not protected
- To assess this condition, you can retrieve all protected ranges of the sheet with [sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype), loop through them and verify either they overlap with the current range (e.g. contain `startRow`)

- Set a boolean variable to `true` if a protection for `range` exists
- Use the boolean inside your `if` condition

Sample:

```js
...
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var protected = false;
  for (var k = 0; k < protections.length; k++){
    var protection = protections[k];
    if(firstRow >= protection.getRange().getRow() && firstRow <= protection.getRange().getLastRow()){
      //range is already protected
      protected = true;
      break;
    }
  }   
  if(dates.indexOf(startDate) != -1 && protected == false){
...
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what this code will do. My condition is that, if there is already a protected range with this particular date, the block of codes won't be executed. A186:F191 is already a  protected range of date 2020-07-31. So again after the protected range two rows were inserted in row 192 and 193 with dates in colA 2020-07-31. So the task is to check whether there is any protected range already with date 2020-07-31. Thus, the code block won't do anything for row 192 and 193 and so on.

Comment: I believe that's what the code snippet above is doing - it checks either the range is alrady protected - and if it is - the `if` statement will evaluate to false.

Comment: It worked fine so far according to what I want. Could I personally contact you. This is part of a voluntary project I am doing for disadvantaged group of schools. The project aims to work with Google Classroom API to make a complete LMS around Google Classroom and distribute free to those schools. This is its attendance system. I need an expert of Google App Scripts to make it happen. Some funding can be managed if you agree.